# Podman Non-Root "Error setting up pivot dir"

Tags: containers, rhel, podman, rhel8

First time posting on StackOverflow so please be gentle!

I'm setting up a new RHEL8 server to run Podman. Previously, I've done this on a pretty vanilla server but this one is setup in line with our corporate image. This means a homedir that is mounted over NFS.

When I try a simple podman command such as `podman run centos`, I get a couple of errors (see below). According to https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/rootless.md, Podman non-root is known to have problems with NFS homedirs.

Output from `podman run centos` (and others):

```
❯ podman run centos
Resolved "centos" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull quay.io/centos/centos:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 7a0437f04f83 done
Error: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:7a0437f04f83f084b7ed68ad9c4a4947e12fc4e1b006b38129bac89114ec3621": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /home/me/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/2653d992f4ef2bfd27f94db643815aa567240c37732cae1405ad1c1309ee9859/diff/.pivot_root926823499: permission denied
```

*No, my username isn't really 'me'*

Is there a way to use podman non-root in this setup? I'd prefer to avoid creating a local user account to run things under (this is my dev server and isn't where the application will actually be running but will involve me building, running, destroying regularly so I'd rather avoid having to do anything 'clever')

Output of `podman info`:

```
❯ podman info
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.23.1
  cgroupControllers: []
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.32-1.module+el8.5.0+13852+150547f7.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.32, commit: 4b12bce835c3f8acc006a43620dd955a6a73bae0'
  cpus: 1
  distribution:
    distribution: '"rhel"'
    version: "8.5"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: servername
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 2000
      size: 1
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 10279927
      size: 1
  kernel: 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: k8s-file
  memFree: 1881419776
  memTotal: 3918233600
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.3-1.module+el8.5.0+13556+7f055e70.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version 1.0.3
      spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.16.7
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/10279927/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module+el8.5.0+12582+56d94c81.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: d361001f495417b880f20329121e3aa431a8f90f
      libslirp: 4.4.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  swapFree: 4294963200
  swapTotal: 4294963200
  uptime: 2h 45m 20.28s (Approximately 0.08 days)
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.centos.org
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/me/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: fuse-overlayfs-1.8-1.module+el8.5.0+13754+92ec836b.x86_64
      Version: |-
        fusermount3 version: 3.2.1
        fuse-overlayfs: version 1.8
        FUSE library version 3.2.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.26
  graphRoot: /home/me/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: nfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 0
  runRoot: /run/user/10279927/containers
  volumePath: /home/me/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.4.2
  Built: 1642068949
  BuiltTime: Thu Jan 13 10:15:49 2022
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.16.7
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.4.2
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am in the same boat. using podman in RHEL rootless mode

Answer (score 2):

Based on this article, https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman-nfs, podman and nfs home directories don't mix well together.

This is worked around by changing the graphroot(which is described in the above article) to write to a local, non-nfs, location.

Comment: How is this answer valid when https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md says "In rootless Podman certain fields in /etc/containers/storage.conf are ignored. These fields are: ... graphroot ..."?

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli is correct: what you are looking for is `rootless_storage_path`. See https://github.com/containers/storage/blob/main/docs/containers-storage.conf.5.md . Also if you're using WSLv2, you might want to use `driver="vfs"` as FUSE is not yet supported on WSLv2