# How can podman build support uid > 65536 in dockerfile

Tags: podman, buildah

I have a `Dockerfile` and want to embed one function user (`bob`) which has same uid (`7200720`) on the working VM

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:focal

RUN groupadd -g 2000 robots 
RUN useradd -m -g 2000 -s /bin/bash -u 7200720 bob

USER bob
```

In docker, it works fine

```
$ docker build -t bob .
$ docker run bob id
uid=7200720(bob) gid=2000(robots) groups=2000(robots)
```

Now I try to migrate to `podman` env (podman v4.1.1)

```
$ podman build -t bob .
..
STEP 4/5: RUN useradd -m -g 2000 -s /bin/bash -u 7200720 bob
useradd: warning: chown on `/home/bob' failed: Invalid argument
..
Successfully tagged localhost/bob:latest
84e7b608fcf45ccedeb8624a88a1692013d5d41cf93954f296ce3351042e0513
..
$ podman run bob id
Error: OCI runtime error: runc: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: setup user: invalid argument
```

Are there anyway to make it working? (I do need big uid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prepare some directories

```
$ mkdir ~/containers
$ mkdir ~/src
$ emacs ~/src/Dockerfile
$ cat ~/src/Dockerfile
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:focal

RUN groupadd -g 2000 robots 
RUN useradd -m -g 2000 -s /bin/bash -u 7200720 bob

USER bob
```

Build the container image

```
$ podman \
   run \
    --privileged \
    --rm \
    --uidmap=0:0:10000 \
    --uidmap=65534:10000:1 \
    --uidmap=7200720:10001:1 \
    -v ~/src:/src:Z \
    -v ~/containers:/var/lib/containers:Z \
     quay.io/buildah/stable buildah bud -t img1 /src
STEP 1/4: FROM docker.io/ubuntu:focal
STEP 2/4: RUN groupadd -g 2000 robots 
STEP 3/4: RUN useradd -m -g 2000 -s /bin/bash -u 7200720 bob
STEP 4/4: USER bob
COMMIT
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:b40ed86654e59e1012e1716d5384910f8c3bb58274b7b00fca564a53e9897ba3
Copying blob sha256:aa3803b76948004897e15aa972c246f69c925a79f2e391d7bccf16be7ec1eb30
Copying config sha256:1030dd7b71bb0c678dcdbae83e26ae896ff661297a8cc8f5743e139f4dcd0a72
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
--> 1030dd7b71b
1030dd7b71bb0c678dcdbae83e26ae896ff661297a8cc8f5743e139f4dcd0a72
```

Test the container image

```
$ podman \
   run \
    --privileged \
    --rm \
    --uidmap=0:0:10000 \
    --uidmap=65534:10000:1 \
    --uidmap=7200720:10001:1 \
    -v ~/containers:/var/lib/containers:Z \
     quay.io/podman/stable \
      bash -c "podman run --rm localhost/img1 \
        bash -c 'echo hello > /home/bob/file1 \
         && id \
         && ls -l /home/bob/file1'"
uid=7200720(bob) gid=2000(robots) groups=2000(robots)
-rw-r--r--. 1 bob robots 4 Sep  3 10:38 /home/bob/file1
$
```

##### Explanation of the --uidmap options

`--uidmap=0:0:10000` maps over all of  smaller UIDs in the container image. The range size 10000 was chosen rather arbitrarily.

I see noticed there are also a few users with a higher UID.

```
$ podman run --rm -ti docker.io/library/ubuntu:focal grep 65534 /etc/passwd
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

so I added an --uidmap for the UID 65534  too   (`--uidmap=65534:10000:1`).

`--uidmap=7200720:10001:1` maps over the UID needed for the user *bob*.

##### Reduce the size of the container image

By adding the useradd option **--no-log-init**, it's possible to reduce the size of the container image from  2.41 GB to 75.2 MB. (I didn't use that option in the examples above).

See also

https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#6-build-hangs-when-the-dockerfile-contains-the-useradd-command

Comment: error creating build container: copying system image from manifest list: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:675920708c8bf10fbd02693dc8f43ee7dbe0a99cdfd55e06e6f1a8b43fd08e3f": processing tar file(setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/b40ed86654e59e1012e1716d5384910f8c3bb58274b7b00fca564a53e9897ba3/diff/.pivot_root868754244: permission denied): exit status 1

I use rootless podman, uid mapping get complicated (uid is 5600)

Comment: hint from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516874/podman-non-root-error-setting-up-pivot-dir, I changed the home folder (nfs) to /local, it works !

Comment: still using buildah-in-podman makes it complicated with uidmap, it will even complicate if I want to do this in k8s.  Is `podman build --userns` useful here

Comment: I first tried `podman build --userns-uid-map=` but I couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure why. I also tried `buildah --userns=auto:uidmapping=...    build`. That didn't work either, but I'm not sure I used the correct syntax. Yes, I agree buildah-in-podman makes it more complicated.

Comment: `--no-log-init` is excellent tip for me